# Trying to display image from firebase storage using url but get an error message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to display the image from firebase storage using the name of the file. The url works and is displayed on the console. But I get the following error: 
[image]
Below is my code:

```
function getFileUrl(filename) {
  var storage = firebase.storage().ref(filename);
  storage.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log(url);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error encountered");
  });
} 

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = getFileUrl(y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `getFileUrl`, which means you're setting `img.src` to `undefined`. And that's precisely what the error message is telling you.

But adding a simple `return` statement isn't possible, since the download URL is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Any code that needs the download URL needs to be inside `then` or be called from there.

```
function createImgForFile(filename) {
  var storage = firebase.storage().ref(filename);
  storage.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = getFileUrl(y);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error encountered");
  });
}
```

---

If you want to make this a bit more reusable, you can return a promise with the URL, meaning that you'll need a `then` when you call it:

```
function getFileUrl(filename) {
  var storage = firebase.storage().ref(filename);
  return storage.getDownloadURL();
} 

var img = document.createElement('img');
getFileUrl(y).then(function(url) {
  img.src = url;
});
```

---

If you find the `then` handlers hard to read, you can use `async`/`await` as some syntactic sugar to make it a bit more familiar looking:

```
function getFileUrl(filename) {
  var storage = firebase.storage().ref(filename);
  return storage.getDownloadURL();
} 

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = await getFileUrl(y);
```